# generate thumbnail when image uploaded django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i have a website where multiple large size images uploaded everyday after they go live because of heavy size its taking time so i want to generate thumbnail version when image uploaded:

```
class Image(models.Model):
      license_type = (
    ('Royalty-Free','Royalty-Free'),
    ('Rights-Managed','Rights-Managed')
                         )
      image_number = models.CharField(default=random_image_number,max_length=12,unique=True)
      title = models.CharField(default=random_image_number,max_length = 100)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'image' , default = 'demo/demo.png')
      thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbs', editable=False)
      category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      shoot = models.ForeignKey(ImageShoot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Image', null=True,blank=True)
      image_keyword = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
      credit = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
      location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
      license_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=license_type, default='')
      uploaded_at = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.title

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

          super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
          if not self.make_thumbnail():
             raise Exception('Could not create thumbnail - is the file type valid?')

      def make_thumbnail(self):
          fh = storage.open(self.Image.name)
          try:
             image = PILImage.open(fh)
          except:
             return False
          image.thumbnail((400,400),PILImage.ANTIALIAS)
          fh.close()
          thumb_name, thumb_extension = os.path.splitext(self.Image.name)
          thumb_extension = thumb_extension.lower()

          thumb_filename = thumb_name + '_thumb' + thumb_extension

          if thumb_extension in ['.jpg', '.jpeg']:
             FTYPE = 'JPEG'
          elif thumb_extension == '.gif':
               FTYPE = 'GIF'
          elif thumb_extension == '.png':
               FTYPE = 'PNG'
          else:
             return False    # Unrecognized file type

    # Save thumbnail to in-memory file as StringIO
         temp_thumb = StringIO()
         image.save(temp_thumb, FTYPE)
         temp_thumb.seek(0)

    # Load a ContentFile into the thumbnail field so it gets saved
         self.thumbnail.save(thumb_filename, ContentFile(temp_thumb.read()), save=True)
         temp_thumb.close()

         return True
```

admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      readonly_fields=['image_number','uploaded_at']
      fields = ['title','image_number','shoot','category',
         'image','image_keyword','credit','license_type','location','uploaded_at']
```

now this is the error:

```
string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

backtrace:

```
File "/home/tboss/Desktop/environment/live/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 779, in _save
ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0) + im.size, 0, rawmode)], bufsize)
File "/home/tboss/Desktop/environment/live/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 513, in _save
fp.write(d)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

when i user BytesIO:

i get this error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

backtrace:

```
 File "/home/tboss/Desktop/environment/live/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 319, in __init__
  if isinstance(value, Fraction):
 File "/home/tboss/Desktop/environment/live/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/abc.py", line 139, in __instancecheck__
 return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)
```

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

i am current uploading image from admin but also going to using drf. currently its not creating thumbnail.............................................................................................................

Comment: have you overwritten save() method of model and call "make_thumbnail" ?

Comment: yes see the edits

Comment: Do you see this exception in the logs ? 'Could not create thumbnail - is the file type valid?'

Comment: Can you indent the code the proper way? It's not clear if the code for saving the thumbnail is correctly indented **inside the `def make_thumbnail()`** method.

Comment: i have make the proper indentation

Comment: its not opening the image at fh = storage.open(self.Image.name)

Comment: The code in your question is not indented correctly.

Comment: Because it should be `fh = storage.open(self.image.name)` (`image` not `Image`)

Comment: And then you have a naming conflict: `Image.open(fh)` what is `Image`? You should `from PIL import Image as PILImage` or something like that to be sure you're using the correct `Image`. Then `PILImage.open(fh)`

Comment: geeting this error expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageFieldFile maybe at os.path.splittext

Comment: your "error handling" prevents you from knowing what's wrong. Remove this catastrophic try/except clause in 'make_thumbnail' and you may have more infos. Also, don't just "return False" if the extension is not what you expect, raise a proper specific exception instead (also note that checking the file extension is not the best way to find out what type your image is)

Comment: Would you be interested in saving the thumbnail as a base64 encoded image? It would be much easier, as the image isa saved as a CharField. If you want help, let me know.

Comment: okay i can work with base64 i just want thumbnails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comment, you can work with base64 encoded image instead. In order to do this, first change the thumbnail field to the following:

```
thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then, override the model save method and add the following code:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    if not self.image:
        self.thumbnail = None
    else:
        thumbnail_size = 50, 50
        data_img = BytesIO()
        tiny_img = Image.open(self.image)
        tiny_img.thumbnail(thumbnail_size)
        tiny_img.save(data_img, format="BMP")
        tiny_img.close()
        try:
            self.thumbnail = "data:image/jpg;base64,{}".format(
                base64.b64encode(data_img.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
            )
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            self.blurred_image = None

    super(Image, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

You can change the thumbnail_size variable to match your needs.
Lastly, add the following to your import section:

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO
```

Don't forget to run makemigrations and migrate commands! Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: i am getting thumbnail field like this data:image/jpg;base64,Qk2eEgAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAMgAAAB8AAAABABgAAAAAAGgSAADEDgAAxA4AAAAAAAAAA but  how can i convert this to image

Comment: This is the image. You can display it in html with <img src="[here goes the base64 string]">

Comment: but when i try to decode this getting some random character

Comment: its working but still size of thumbnail is about 340pk of 3mb image can you recommend something to compress thumbnail image cause it will take time to load

Comment: You can check base64 images in this link https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
Have you tried to reduce the thumbnail size?

Comment: The size of the image in the pastebin is 5kB which is more than fine in my opinion

Comment: no i didn't any idea how to reduce the thumbnail size

Comment: it was smaller image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205600/discussion-between-george-bikas-and-afk).

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use Django Advance Thumbnail.
Here's a basic example of how to use the AdvanceDJThumbnailField in a model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_advance_thumbnail import AdvanceThumbnailField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    my_image_thumbnail = AdvanceThumbnailField(source_field='my_image', upload_to='images/thumbnails/', null=True, blank=True,
                                  size=(300, 300))
```

In this example, `AdvanceDJThumbnailField` is used to create a `thumbnail` from the `image` field. Whenever an image is `uploaded` or `updated`, a corresponding thumbnail is `automatically` `generated` and stored in the thumbnail field. The thumbnail's dimensions are determined by the optional size parameter, which defaults to (300, 300) if not specified.

*This setup ensures that the lifecycle of the thumbnail is tied to its source image. If the source image is deleted, the associated thumbnail is also removed. This seamless synchronization simplifies image management in your Django models.*

**Installation of Django Advance Thumbnail**.

`pip install django_advance_thumbnail`

Add `django_advance_thumbnail` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django_advance_thumbnail',
    # ...
]
```