# Make thumbnail after ImageField save

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to make thumbnail of an uploaded image after the Imagefield model is saved. At this moment i'm getting raise Exception error: Could not create thumbnail - is the file type valid?". Can you guys help me how to get it working?

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image as Img


class Image(models.Model):
    img_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=User)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="thumbs", editable=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_added"]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.make_thumbnail():
            # set to a default thumbnail
            raise Exception("Could not create thumbnail - is the file type valid?")
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def make_thumbnail(self):
        size = 128, 128

        im = Img.open(self.image)
        im.thumbnail(size)
        im.save(self.image.name + ".thumbnail", "PNG")
```

seralizers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Image


class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="img_owner.username")
    thumbnail = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ["url", "author", "img_owner", "image", "thumbnail", "date_added"]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets

from .models import Image
from .serializers import ImageSerializer


class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    """
    Bellow definition overrides queryset and filter images by loged user.
    """

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Image.objects.filter(img_owner=user)
```

EDIT: I managed to do thumbinals with below code on models.py but im getting now an *ValueError at /images/, The 'thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it.* Second problem my thumbnail image is saving at main project directory not in media folder.

new models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
# from main.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from PIL import Image as Img


class Image(models.Model):
    img_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=User)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="tumbs", editable=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_added"]

    def save(
        self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None
    ):
        if not self.image:
            self.thumbnail = None
        else:
            size = 128, 128

            im = Img.open(self.image)
            im.thumbnail(size)
            im.save("thumb_" + self.image.name, "PNG")

        super(Image, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Comment: I hope it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644151/generate-thumbnail-when-image-uploaded-django

Comment: I solved this issue with a JS line:
on forms.py added (relevant input field for images)
'onchange': 'document.getElementById("imageBox").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])',
then on template:
<p>Avatar preview:</p>
                    <img id="imageBox" src="#" alt="" style="max-width: 200px;"/>

not adding a new answer since it's not strictly affine to your example

Answer (score 0):

Note it will create thumbnail on every save(), consider adding another check before it

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings  # it's the correct way to import settings
from PIL import Image as Img
from pathlib import Path


class Image(models.Model):
    img_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=User)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="tumbs", editable=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_added"]  # it's not recommended to set ordering at model level.

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.image:
            self.thumbnail = None  # note, this will not delete the file
        else:
            size = 128, 128

            im = Img.open(self.image)
            im.thumbnail(size)
            name = Path(self.image.name)
            # omit Path() if MEDIA_ROOT is already a Path object
            thb_path = Path(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) / f"thumb_{name.stem}.png" 
            self.thumbnail = thb_path.name  # it's should be relative path
             
            im.save(thb_path, "PNG")  # if it doesn't like Path, str() it

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```